# Propagating tap events down through invisible UIButton

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a couple of UIButtons in the view which "floats" above UIScrollView (i.e. scrolling of the UIScrollView does not influence the buttons' position on the screen). My application logic sometimes requre hiding one of those buttons, and when it happens the UIScrollView could not be scrolled bu dragging from the point inside the (invisible) button (it "swallows" the event).

I've looked at the hitTest:withEvent:, but not sure that this is the best/easiest way to do this (both UIButton and UIScrollView are not customized, and I don't want to make custom classes for any of them just for this purpose).

Is there any better way to propagate the event to the view below?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able make the buttons ignore the touch events by calling...

```
[button setUserInteractionEnabled:NO]
```